# Difference between bounding box, envelope, extent, bounds?

Tags: geometry, extents, gis-principle, terminology, bbox

Every time when I create a script to manipulate vector (point, line and polygon) in python I meet this doubt.

What is the difference between bounding box (bbox), envelope, extent, bounds?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you'll find there is a bit of overlap with these definitions. They're all very similar, in my opinion. However, ESRI has a glossary of GIS terms, so I just looked them up. The definitions are similar or identical to the [wiki GIS glossary](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjXtMvT_frTAhVHHZQKHWggBzoQFggvMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.gis.com%2Fwiki%2Findex.php%2FGIS_Glossary&usg=AFQjCNE8YOdbCyqI-3LrDDCnQsDDq2BN7A&sig2=em3QQ1u5OUo2IA_HqHNK-w) as well.

[Bounding Box (Bounding Rectangle)](http://support.esri.com/other-resources/gis-dictionary/term/bounding%20rectangle):

> [map display] The rectangle, aligned with the coordinate axes and
>   placed on a map display, that encompasses a geographic feature or
>   group of features or an area of interest. It is defined by minimum and
>   maximum coordinates in the x and y directions and is used to
>   represent, in a general way, the location of a geographic area.

[Extent](http://support.esri.com/other-resources/gis-dictionary/term/extent):

> The minimum bounding rectangle (xmin, ymin and xmax, ymax) defined by
>   coordinate pairs of a data source. All coordinates for the data source
>   fall within this boundary.

It should be noted that in the [arcpy documentation for extent](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/extent.htm) (though you haven't said which software you're using), the definition is essentially the same:

> An extent is a rectangle specified by providing the coordinate of the
>   lower left corner and the coordinate of the upper right corner in map
>   units.

[Extent Rectangle](http://support.esri.com/other-resources/gis-dictionary/term/extent%20rectangle) (you didn't ask for this one, but it was in the glossary so I threw it in):

> [ESRI software] A rectangle that is displayed in one data frame,
>   showing the size and position of another data frame.

The glossary doesn't have a definition for bounds, but I think it would likely be similar or identical to extent.  It should be noted there is also a term called "metes and bounds", which is not really what you're asking, but I thought I would include it anyway.

[Metes and Bounds](http://support.esri.com/other-resources/gis-dictionary/term/metes%20and%20bounds):

> A surveying method in which the limits of a parcel are identified as
>   relative distances and bearings from landmarks. Metes and bounds
>   surveying often resulted in irregularly shaped areas.

Finally, there is a tool in ArcGIS called [Minimum Bounding Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm) which:

> Creates a feature class containing polygons which represent a
>   specified minimum bounding geometry enclosing each input feature or
>   each group of input features.

Depending on which option you choose, the results will be different.  However, it's worth noting that the Envelope option is a polygon which appears to be to be identical to the extent.

Comment: A bounding box can be thought of a something that encloses the extent, it doesn't have to match the extent.  In OGC web services the bounding box can be used to define a `hint` of the location of the data, to facilitate data searching.